# Can losing weight from diarrhea affect chest muscles?

Tags: body-fat, chest, illness

So I recently lost like 2 kg from diarrhea and now I notice that my chest isn't pumped up anymore (or my tummy has swollen from the diarrhea)

I also haven't been able to exercise for 2 weeks (before today) due to the same reason. So can diarrhea affect chest muscles?

Answer (score 2):

In the short term, no you should not feel any adverse effects from a bout of illness.  However, if it becomes a chronic condition, that may lead to muscle deterioration as your body is constantly In recovery and you are not able to get to the gym.  In general, depending on your current fitness level, it takes a while to lose appreciable muscle mass.  You can read more about it in my response to [How long does it take for my muscles to grow weaker if i skip the gym?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/33864/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-muscles-to-grow-weaker-if-i-skip-the-gym/33870#33870)